# DOM HTML PARSING

Tags: html, dom

***Source.HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 style="color:red">Hello World</h1>
<p id="demo" style="color:red">Click the button below to remove the style attribute from the header above.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

***Parser.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Parse</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].removeAttribute("style"); 
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].removeAttribute("style");
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now what i need guidance for was , i need the Parse button from parser.html to apply the functions for source.html and save as output.html in same path of source.html...

Kindly help me out ...

Comment: You'd need to use a server side language, something like PHP, to work with the file system.
Your javascript functions wouldn't work well with this, I think the FileSystem API is limited. You want to look into PHP and AJAX

Comment: This is not about parsing at all. Parsing is what a browser does for constructing a DOM tree. Thus, when you manipulate the DOM, the document must already have been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

What Willshaw said is correct. Javascript don't have that much power to solve your problem. You need to go for some serverside scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, it is a pretty strange way to do.

But, the DOM parsing being really easy with javascript, you could do the parsing on the client side, I guess, and then send the processed html to your backend, and save it in result.html.

I will use Jquery for the example, way easier.

**Parser.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btnLoad">Load Source</button>
<button id="btnParse">Parse</button>
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>

<div style="display:none" id="sourceContainer"></div> 

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".btnLoad").click(function(){$("#sourceContainer").load("/source.html");})
    $(".btnParse").click(function(){
       $(".sourceContainer h1").removeAttr("style");
       $(".sourceContainer p").removeAttr("style");
    })
    $(".btnSave").click(function(){
       var data = {
          html: $("#sourceContainer").html()
       };
       //replace first param by the backend url, add callback function
       $.post("http://...", data, ...);
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really expect it to work when you copy/paste the code above in a style tag? (I checked your example in chrome inspector)